# why the following regular expression does not work in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use some regex in python for pattern matching.
I am looking at a very simple example, but this does not work as I expected.
the snippet is as follows. I expected it to print "match", but it did not

```
>>> line="123 a bcdef12"
>>> data_headers = re.compile('.*a bc.* ')
>>> if data_headers.match(line):
...     print "match"
... 
>>>
```

I also tried the following:

```
>>> data_headers = re.compile(' a bc* ')
>>> data_headers = re.compile('.*a bc* ')
```

but both did not find any match.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: looks fine maybe the space in the end of the stirng? '.*a bc.* '

Comment: @FooBarUser the problem is that space indeed : http://regex101.com/r/gI6yX9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space at the end is what's stopping it from matching:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(".*a bc.* ", "123 a bcdef12")
None
>>> re.match(".*a bc.*", "123 a bcdef12")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdd6c462b90>
```

You might find a tool such as [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) (there are many others) useful for testing and debugging regex expressions.